# Android ListView: Do I need to create another class to use it?

Tags: android

I have an app using an ScrollView and it loads a lot of images.

I decided to change to ListView. I saw that to use ListView, my class must extend ListActivity.

My current class does a lot of things, like inserting in database, updating, etc.

So, should I create a new classe just for the ListView? Can I just say that my current class now extends ListActivity?

In case I need to create a separate class just for the ListView, how do I use it in my current class?

Any help is appreciated!

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class doesn't necessary have to extend `ListActivity` you could use a simple `Activity` with a `ListView` element in it's layout. To use your existing activity just replace the current `ScrollView` element with a `ListView` element. Then retrieve this element in `onCreate()` and set its adapter that will map the images to the `ListView` rows. You will have to make your own custom adapter to show the images.

Answer (score 1):

ListActivity is just a sub-class of Activity.

Its the same but it allows you to have utility methods such as setListAdapter() and also manages stuff like showing a placeholder when there is nothing in the list by looking for @android:id/empty in your inflated layout.

Using ListActivity it helps to manage the List that with the id of @android:id/list. It works just as well managing your own list without the ListActivity,it wont break your current code if used correctly just have to make an adapter for the list..